# Multi server tchat with Nginx and Nodejs Socket IO

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

My problem : What is the (best) way for ... ?

- I want to deploy a Nodejs app using SocketIO for chat client
- I have 3 servers with load-balancing on nginx
- In use, admit User1 socket is created on Server 1 and User2 socket is created on server2
- Then, User1 send message to User2

How my server1 now that User2 is on server2 ? How to transmit the message ?

- Maybe a shared database or shared redis with treatment pool of thread on each server
- Maybe... A better choice :)

Thanks !